# Recommendations for .NET Restful Web Service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, rest

I need to create a RESTful web service in VB.net. I can't find any code examples or information on this that isn't a few years old. What are my options? Are there 3rd party libraries most people use? Should I be using an MVC (5, 6?) project? The only information I can find is from 2010-2011 and I want to use the latest/greatest technology available.

Anything that can point me in the right direction or how to research this further would be helpful.

Comment: it is called the Web API in its current incarnation. http://www.asp.net/web-api

Answer (score -1):

REST is a very old technique to implement webservices. Not as old as SOAP.
I created a webservice with Java on Tomcat a few weeks ago but had to watch some tutorials. Those are also 4 to 5 years old. You can use these tutorials as well because standards don't change that much.

If you would like to create a webservice in Java (JAX-RS) I can send you some good sites with tutorials. :)

Comment: The OP specified that he is using VB.NET.

Comment: Yeah. But I just want to show him other directives and ways. Perhaps this will help him, you can not know.